# Deleting Multiple files from multiple directories

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am trying to delete specific files in multiple places. I could do this manually but there are hundreds of file names. I'd really love to automate this. I currently have a debug log that I pull specific bad file names from and store them in a text file using the following in powershell:

```
$debugFile = "C:\Users\username\log\debug.log"
$tmpFile = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\tmpFile.txt"
$filters = "ValueError: Invalid file"
$badFiles = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\badFiles.txt"
Get-Content $debugFile | Select-String -pattern $filters -SimpleMatch | Out-File $tmpFile
Get-Content $tmpFile | % {$_ -replace "ValueError: Invalid file ", ""} | Out-File $badFiles
```

The bad files in the badFiles.txt include the full path and are all of the same type, but they are saved on different drives (D:, E:, F:, etc.), but none are saved on the C:\ drive.

Example of badFiles.txt contents:

```
D:\badfile.txt
D:\badfile2.txt
D:\badfile3.txt
E:\badfile.txt
F:\badfile.txt
F:\badfile2.txt
```

There are also other files in the same directories of the same file type that must not be deleted.
Sorry if this was lengthy, but I thought it was better to give more info than not enough. Also, my experience with this kind of thing is none. I only got as far as I did, thanks to Google and StackOverflow. But I'd love to learn more about this kind of thing.

Comment: So all it takes is [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) or am I missing something?

Comment: @Theo, dumb and off topic question but, how do you substitute the url link, to a custom word(s).

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `[word(s) here](url here)`